# Extend a continuous function on $\partial\Omega$ to inside with higher regularity?

Tags: derivatives, surfaces

Let $\Omega$ be a $C^3$ (or, $C^k$) bounded domain. Say a continuous function $\phi$ is defined on the boundary, i.e., $\phi\in C^0(\partial\Omega)$.

My question is

i) can we find an extension $\widetilde{\phi}$ such that $\widetilde{\phi}\in C^3(\Omega)$ and $\widetilde{\phi}\big|_{\partial\Omega}=\phi$? I'm not requiring the higher regularity $C^3$ even upto the boundary, because it's gonna be too much.

ii) can we ask the same for $C^2$ extensions? for $C^1$ extensions?

iii) any related results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just take any differential operator for which you establish the regularity of the solution of the boundary value problem... Determine $u$ such that
\begin{cases} {\mathcal L} u = 0, &\Omega \\ u=\phi, & \partial \Omega\end{cases}
and take $u$ as the extension of $\phi$. Example: the Laplace operator ${\mathcal L}:= \Delta$.

Comment: This is great! Are there any conditions on the domain $\Omega$? Because what I'm having in mind is the famous resolution with a ball and the Laplace operator. I can require $\Omega$ to be $C^3$ and bounded, is it enough?

Comment: I thought you only gain 1/2 power of regularity over the boundary by solving the Laplace equation. That is, $||u||_{H^{k+2}} \le C ||\phi||_{H^{k+3/2}}$, and this bound is sharp. E.g., page 219 in Arbogasts "Methods of Applied Mathematics" notes, which you can find online. But my memory on elliptic regularity is hazy, so I could be wrong

Comment: @NickAlger Now you make me wonder... But I was under the impression that if $g$ is the trace of some  $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u = 0$ in the weak sense in $\Omega$ then we actually have that $u \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$.